# How to update lucene index synchronously?

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I have created a Lucene index (using Lucene.net) and the search is working fine.

My concern is as follows:

I used data from my SQL database to create an index. Now the thing is, this data is growing and I am unable to find a way to modify the index without deleting and recreating it. Please let me know if there is a way of modifying the lucene index without the delete-recreate process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IndexWriter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html) has methods like `addDocument`, `updateDocument`, and `deleteDocuments`, which are used to modify data in the index.  Updating a document does require the document to be deleted and reindexed behind the scenes, but it shouldn't require you to recreate the entire index.